# Note 5 with Android 5.1 can't read permission about Read Contacts

Tags: java, android, samsung-mobile

I'm working on app and after uploaded this through Google Play store I have one report from user of Note 5 with Android 5.1 like this:

```
java.lang.SecurityException: Permission Denial: reading com.android.providers.contacts.ContactsProvider2 uri content://com.android.contacts/phone_lookup/4456 from pid=7056, uid=10231 requires android.permission.READ_CONTACTS, or grantUriPermission()
```

and after searched about this problem i read this is happened only in Samsung devices specifically Note 5 with Android 5.1 .

I don't know how i can solved this !!

Note : I know everything about permission also the application is working very good on another devices only this device Note 5 we have this problem and another problem about pick image from device and send it through Java Mail API

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Failure delivering result ResultInfo{who=null, request=101, result=-1, data=Intent { dat=content://com.android.providers.media.documents/document/image:2144 flg=0x1 }}
```